# Data brokers for market-related data, how to choose, where to look for?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, marketing

**Situation**

I am doing a data science project for my client. Due to NDA I can't disclose anything to the nature of the project, but let's imagine that they manufacture and sell slow cookers.

I faced the need to get the dataset which will cover all of the 'slow cooker' products in the selected market. The information we want is the list of features of each product. For example a record should have product name and brand + capacity, material, color, cord length etc., everything you could see on a product listing page in something like Amazon. The more detailed it is the better.

Beyond that we want either a comprehensive set of product review texts from leading ecommerce platforms. If not available - at least average (also min and max) customer sentiment of such reviews.

**Issue**

I already did a prototype research by just doing a web-scraping of one of eCommerce web-sites. The issue is that:

- It took quite a while
- It is not really comprehensive - I want to cover all leading eCommerce platforms.
- Scraping more platforms will take a lot of time, and normalizing and merging scraping results will be a big pain.

On the other hand, client is OK to just pay some money to buy clean dataset from company which already did that - data brokers.

But the issue I faced is that even though I spent a lot of time googling data brokers I wasn't able to come up with a good list and clearly understand if these companies actually sell the kind of data I want. And honestly if you google 'data broker' absolute majority of results will give you some angry articles from newspapers about 'companies who know more about you than google', not the links to actual companies and the description of what kinds of data they provide.

**Question**

Bottom line - is there any advice on how to approach the issue of looking for a good data broker and choosing it? Is there any good resource which covers market leaders in this area with a comprehensive information on which kinds of data they sell?

Extra question: I remember some time ago Microsoft launched so-called Azure Data Mart which supposed to be a one-stop shop for datasets sold by various companies, but seems like the idea dies without further development. I wonder if anyone knows of such successful data marts which can be used?

**Why I didn't post it on opendata**

Answer is simple - I am not looking for open (free) data. Our clients are OK to pay for it. At the same time, OpenData community requires questions to cover only OpenData.